# How to pass the value of a constant of a specific func in a button func to use it as destination of the navigation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, mapkit

How can i use the constant in this function

```
func didSelect(place:QPlace) {

    guard let coordinates = place.location  else {
        return
    }

    // clear current marker
    marker?.map = nil

    // add marker
    marker = GMSMarker()
    marker?.position = coordinates
    marker?.title = place.name
    marker?.map = mapView
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker
    moveToMarker(marker!)

    // update bottom info panel view
    let desc = place.getDescription()
    descriptionLabel.text = desc.characters.count > 0 ? desc : "-"
    distanceLabel.text = "-"

    // update distance
    if userLocation != nil {
        let dist = distance(from: userLocation!, to: coordinates)
        distanceLabel.text = String.init(format: "Distance %.2f meters", dist)
        self.drawPath(startLocation: userLocation!, endLocation: coordinates)
    }

    title = place.name
}
```

(so the constant `coordinates`) to get the destination here

```
  @IBAction func navigationStart(_ sender: Any) {

  let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5007, -0.1246)
    let placeMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placeMark)
    mapItem.name = "Big Ben"
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])

}
```

where i open the map after the tap of a button, so i want that let coordinate = coordinates, how can i do?

Comment: Declare `destPosition` as a property (at class-level)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it looks like you want to hold a reference to the location passed in and use it later. So that suggests:

1. Create an instance variable `var destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D?`
2. assign the destination from the method:

   ```
   func didSelect(place:QPlace) {
       destination = place.location
   }
   ```
3. Set the destination

   ```
   @IBAction func navigationStart(_ sender: Any) {
       if let coordinate = self.destination {
           let placeMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
           let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placeMark)
           mapItem.name = "Big Ben"
           mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: 
               [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: 
               MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
       }
   }
   ```

I based it off of your code assuming it works. Did not check the types. That should be an easy fix if it does not work. But the main logic is this.

UPDATE FOR 2.:

```
func didSelect(place:QPlace) {
    guard let coordinates = place.location  else {
        return
    }
    // ADD THIS
    self.destination = coordinates

    // clear current marker
    marker?.map = nil

    // add marker
    marker = GMSMarker()
    marker?.position = coordinates
    marker?.title = place.name
    marker?.map = mapView
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker
    moveToMarker(marker!)

    // update bottom info panel view
    let desc = place.getDescription()
    descriptionLabel.text = desc.characters.count > 0 ? desc : "-"
    distanceLabel.text = "-"

    // update distance
    if userLocation != nil {
        let dist = distance(from: userLocation!, to: coordinates)
        distanceLabel.text = String.init(format: "Distance %.2f meters", dist)
        self.drawPath(startLocation: userLocation!, endLocation: coordinates)
    }

    title = place.name
}
```

Comment: sorry i edited the question with the complete function, if i take away the guard let, i get a lot of errors in the code

Comment: @Tvenden try this. Again the logic is the same. hold reference to the location and update to that in the button click method.